# How do I check if a given object is an instance of certain class when in Object[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, instance

I was trying to find out how to determine which class a given object instantiate when it's in Object[] array. For example:

```
Object[] array = new Object[]{175, "sss", new Table(), true};
Object obj = array[0]; // hmm... can this be used as an integer or maybe as a string?
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why are you storing everything in an `Object` array?

Comment: I use an Object array to store parameters for calling Lua functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `getClass()` to find out the class of a particular object, or you can use `instanceof` to check a specific type:

```
if (array[0] instanceof Integer) {
}
```

Normally having to do a lot of this indicates a weakness in your design though - you should *try* to avoid needing to do this.

Comment: Specifically it may be no Integer but int

Comment: He has an array of Object, so you are sure there are no int

Comment: @MichalBorek `instanceof` works only on objects and `int` is not an object. If you asign `int` to `Object`, it will be automatically converted to `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `instanceof` or you can try `getClass().isAssignableFrom()`, whatever fits your needs

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether it is an instance of a pre-known class (and cast it) like this:

```
if (obj instanceof String) {
  String s = (String) obj; //casts the obj now you know it's a String
}
```

I like to think of this not as making any changes to the object but just as revealing its true character. For example, it's a bit like seeing a person and not knowing what language they speak - the person is still French, or Italian, just that you don't know which yet. The cast (i.e. `(String) obj`) is you telling the compiler the equivalent of *"I know this person speaks French"*

Or you can gets its class like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
```

A `Class` instance can be used to make the same check:

```
String.class.isInstance(obj) {
  String s = String.class.cast(obj);
}
```